# How to generate FB Page access token

Tags: php, facebook

I have a Page with ID: 1620295414849355
I need to generate Page Access Token.
Need Page access token to post content on FB page from my website.

Comment: please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ...and then check out the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens - or this article: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to generate app token in the debug tool and then select your page from drop down present in the right side of access token.Then you will get the page access token in the same input box.

[image]

Comment: sorry not in debug tool.In graph api explorer

Comment: Will share the screen shots